# Why say Adam listened to Eve if she merely gave him fruit?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, speech-talking, adam

In Genesis 3 Eve simply hands over to Adam the forbidden fruit. If this is so, then why did G-d say "because you listened to your wife and ate fruit from the tree"?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!  You may need to provide some background, and possibly a reference, if you want readers to understand the Gilgamesh reference.  Can you expand your first question?  I don't quite see what point is bothering you.

Comment: Terrance, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your questions here! As these two questions are not clearly related, I recommend that you [edit] one out and consider posting it as a separate post. Also, what @YeZ said while I was typing the same things. Finally, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: As you now have an answer to the first question, I've gone ahead and [edited out](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/50834/3) the second one. Please feel free to post it, duly clarified, as a new post.

Answer (score 2):

The commentary [Ohr Hachaim on Breishit 3:17](http://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.3.17) states that Eve did speak to Adam, whose mistake was that he didn't check and ask his wife which tree the fruit came from, but simply just listened to his wife when she told him to eat the "forbidden fruit".

Keep in mind that in the Torah, the term "listen" doesn't necessarily imply that there was a conversation and that listening was done using the ears. Often this term means "obeying".

Comment: +1. I hope you don't mind that I replaced your link with one that's easier to read. If you do mind, rollback the edit, by all means.